# Invalid characters in json response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am unable to process the json response ,while accessing  the json response I am getting some invalid characters in the json response,so How can we remove white space issues and invalid characters from the json response using php scirpt

My json Response :

```
[{"keyword":"cosmetic dermatology","svol":4400},{"keyword":"dermatology associates","svol":22200},{"keyword"
:"advanced dermatology","svol":40500},{"keyword":"dermatology clinic","svol":3600},{"keyword":"dermatology
 specialists","svol":3600},{"keyword":"dermatology consultants","svol":5400},{"keyword":"pediatric dermatology"
,"svol":3600},{"keyword":"what is dermatology","svol":1900},{"keyword":"dermatology pictures","svol"
:1300},{"keyword":"dermatological","svol":2400},{"keyword":"laser dermatology","svol":1300},{"keyword"
:"dermatology group","svol":1900},{"keyword":"dermatology uk","svol":390},{"keyword":"dermatology courses"
,"svol":1000},{"keyword":"dermatologic","svol":1600},{"keyword":"westlake dermatology","svol":8100},
{"keyword":"pariser dermatology","svol":3600},{"keyword":"aesthetic dermatology","svol":1000},{"keyword"
:"dermatology doctors","svol":590},{"keyword":"north dallas dermatology","svol":1300} ]
```

And My JQuery is:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"post", 
            datatype : 'json',
            url:"GetKeyWordBids.php", 
            data:"specialty="+ spevalue,
            success: function(s) {
                var object = $.parseJSON(s);
                /*oTable.fnClearTable();
                oTable.fnAddData([
                    s
                ]); */
            }
        });
```

FireBug Output:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 25230 of the JSON data
```

And Jsonlint.com output for json response:

```
Parse error on line 75:
...        "keyword": "ear nose and throat
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Comment: your JSON response is having line breaks , when I tested in JSONLINT. I removed those breaks and it worked completely. May be you want to check the JSON response emitting mechanism to check the invalid characters

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `$.parseJSON();` since `datatype : 'json'` is specified. the returned data is already in the JSON format just use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Please paste your JSON data here:
http://jsonlint.com/
and see that the JSON syntax is bad.

When you'll fix that, use Satpal answer (don't include $.parseJSON)